# Windows Phone 8 Map, Databinding Map modes only works one time

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have a model with properties:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List of available map modes
    /// </summary>
    public Array MapModes { get; private set; } 

    /// <summary>
    /// The current cartographic mode of the map
    /// </summary>
    public MapCartographicMode MapMode
    {
        get { return _mapMode; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _mapMode) return;
            _mapMode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of available map color modes
    /// </summary>
    public Array MapColorModes { get; private set; }

    //The current color mode of the map
    public MapColorMode MapColorMode
    {
        get { return _mapColorMode; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _mapColorMode) return;
            _mapColorMode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And My XAML looks like this:

```
 <maps:Map x:Name="MainMap"
                                  Height="{Binding MapHeight}"
                                  ColorMode="{Binding MapColorMode, Converter={StaticResource MapTestConverter}}">
```

The properties are updated on another page.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Map mode"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding MapModes}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MapMode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Map color mode"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding MapColorModes}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MapColorMode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Now the binding of the ListPickers works fine the value in the model always represents what was last picked here.

The Map binding also works, it gets the initial value and also updates the first time I change a property.

BUT that's it. after the first property change it refuses to update. (The dummy IValueConverter isn't called).

The model still nicely raises Property changed events, and the property has the correct value in the model (manually assigning it for example at page load works flawlessly)

Since it seems the Binding is getting "broken" I tried recreating it each time the property was updated

```
        Binding b = new Binding("MapMode");
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(MainMap, Map.CartographicModeProperty, b);
```

This works. I am beginning to think there is a bug or something in the wp8 map implementation. (Or I may just miss something completely obvious^^)

Comment: Could you show your OnPropertyChanged() method?
Normally when you raise that method you pass the Public property name into that method

Comment: I updated it, I went over it with the debugger it uses the correct name.

Comment: Do you have anything changing the datacontext?

Comment: Not that I know of, what could do that other than an explicit DataContext = ... in the code behind? What is interesting though, while debugging the OnPropertyChanged() I noticed that the "InvocationCount" property of the handler variable decreases by 1 after the first update. So it really seems to remove itself from the databinding oO

Comment: It also only does that on an successful update. For example when changing Road to Terrain, after changing Light to Dark, this fails (don't now why) -> no change on the map. But the InvocationCount does not decrease. Then if I change it to for example aerial it works, map updates and InvocationCount decreases. And no further updates will work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same.
The solution is to provide Mode=TwoWay to the bindings. I have no idea why that works, but it seems. 
On this blog I have seen exactly this solution:
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.ch/2012/10/introducing-new-windows-8-map-control.html